# Getting "error while emitting; method too large" while creating dataframe in databricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am creating a dataframe in a function and returning that dataframe

```
def getDataFrame(rdd: RDD[MyCaseClass]) = {
    spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
  }
```

The file in which this function is present compiles without any error. While running this in another file throws error:

```
%run "./Load_Dataframe"

The execution of this command did not finish successfully

import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
defined class MyCaseClass
error: Error while emitting $$$cbf4485eb7852af86a790a85973a466$$$$w$STHierarchy$$typecreator1$1
Method too large: $$$cbf4485eb7852af86a790a85973a466$$$$w$STHierarchy$$typecreator1$1.apply (Lscala/reflect/api/Mirror;)Lscala/reflect/api/Types$TypeApi;
```

Most of the solutions online tells to divide the function into multiple smaller function. But my function has only single line of code not sure how I can divide it into multiple functions.

Comment: you have very complex transformation somewhere, or you have too many fields in your case class, or something like. but it's hard to say without looking into complete code

Answer (score 3):

I have asked this question. Below are the steps which I have taken to resolve this issue. I have no idea about the root cause of this issue and I just know that these workaround works:

1. Detach and reattach the cluster. This resolves the issue 80% of the time.
2. Restart the cluster and then try again.
3. There is a very big class in your file, It would be better if you break it into multiple classes.
4. There is a huge function in your file. Break that function into multiple smaller functions.

In my case I had a huge class which I break into two classes and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart your cluster.
This has resolved after restarting the cluster

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).